# In c++ can memory writes be delayed by optimization or do I need volatile?

Tags: c++, volatile

I've read dozens of questions and answers here about the use of volatile and I apologize for posting yet another but I don't think I've seen exactly what I'm looking for.

I have a library written in C++ for Arduino microcontrollers. I have an ISR that fills a buffer and when it's finished it sets a flag to let the outside world know there is data available. I have the buffer, a variable telling how many bytes in the buffer, and the flag telling the world the buffer has data. Once I set that "I'm finished filling the buffer" flag in the ISR, the ISR will never change the buffer or its length again until/unless I reenable things.

Typically I have had the flag, the buffer, and the length value all declared volatile because that's what you're supposed to do in ISR routines.

However I do a lot of processing of that buffer once it is full and that means I'm cheating myself out of some potential optimizations. Outside my ISR if I had code that reads something like

```
if (flag== FINISHED) {
  disable_my_ISR (); 
   /*do a bunch of stuff with the buffer*/
  reenable_my_ISR();
}
```

Then theoretically I think I need not have my buffer as volatile. Is that correct? As I said my concern is that my "do a bunch of stuff with the buffer" is not getting optimized because the buffer is volatile.

The only other answer I've seen anywhere on this forum was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25614728/4500455) however I'm not sure that's really the same circumstance.

Comment: I should add that this buffer is global to the entire program. Also that this is a single processor environment. There are not simultaneous threads. I realize that threads and volatile don't really have a lot to do with one another. Threaded as a whole another monster :-)

Answer (score 2):

When you mark something as `volatile` you are saying that its value might change between writes/reads in your code. And that is exactly what can happen when an ISR accesses the variable, so you need `volatile`.

Any variable shared between your ISR and your main code should be `volatile`. Your code might work without marking everything, but it will come back to bite you eventually.

> Then theoretically I think I need not have my buffer as volatile.

No, your buffer needs to be marked `volatile` if it is used by both your main code and your ISR. I think you're probably worrying too much about missing optimizations. You could always copy the `volatile` array into a normal array, do your processing, and time the difference.

Comment: I perhaps overcomplicated example. If I guarantee that my outside code only accesses the buffer while the ISR is disabled then my claim is that even though the rule of thumb is "Everything accessed both inside and outside any ISR should be volatile" in my case I guarantee that I only access the the buffer when the ISR disabled.

Comment: To continue my explanation… 
As a matter of implementation, I'm leaving the ISR active. One version of it is on a timer and a different version is a pin change interrupt. But even though the hardware interrupts are still enabled, my ISR is effectively doing nothing because I've set a flag that tells it "don't do anything, act as though you are disabled and exit immediately if this flag is set".

As far as copying the data to a separate buffer, Arduino microcontrollers typically only have about 2K of RAM memory so that's not an option.

Comment: You said "When you mark something as volatile you're saying that its value might change between writes/reads in your code." I'm saying that despite the fact there is an ISR involved, I'm using my own means to ensure that outside the ISR the data is never accessed while it could potentially be changed by the ISR.

Answer (score 2):

It's not even that the memory writes can be delayed by an optimisation - if your buffer is not declared `volatile`, your compiler can potentially remove any code using it. Take this example:

```
int myBuffer[5] = {0};
if(flag == FINISHED) {
    printf("%d", myBuffer[0]);
}
```

This may very well always print `0`, even though your ISR changed the value of the buffer, because the compiler does not know how the ISR can change the program flow and hence assumes that `myBuffer[0]` will be 0 when it is used.

Comment: Is that example code that you given still true if the buffer is global to the entire program? I can see that if I declare a buffer inside of function and do things with that buffer inside the function that the compiler should feel free to assume it knows everything that I'm doing with that buffer. I guess I neglected to mention in my original question that the buffer is global to the entire module.